# Header php function

Tags: php, html

I have a problem redirecting using header function. The code is as below.

```
 <?php 
 include_once('connectdb.php');    
 $from=  $_POST['select-choice-1'];
 $to=  $_POST['select-choice-2'];
$date=  $_POST['date'];
$time=  $_POST['time'];
$no_of_seats=  $_POST['passengerno'];  
if (isset($_POST['select-choice-1']) && isset($_POST['select-choice-2']) &&      isset($_POST['date']) &&
isset($_POST['time']) && isset($_POST['passengerno']) && !empty($_POST['select-choice-1']) && !empty($_POST['select-choice-2']) 
&& !empty($_POST['date']) && !empty($_POST['time']) && !empty($_POST['passengerno'])) {
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT email,phone FROM driverjourneydetails WHERE jfrom='$from' 
AND jto='$to' AND date='$date' AND time='$time' AND no_of_seats_avail='$no_of_seats'");     
$rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
//print_r($_POST);
 if($rows>0){
 header("location: availableCars.php");
}else{   
echo "No available cars on your route";
}  }
else echo "Missing fields. Please all the required fields.";
?>
```

In my database there is a row of matching meaning the `header()` func. is called but here is the error displayed on my current page despite the fact that without the header function everything is working fine

> **Notice: Undefined index: select- choice-1 in C:\wamp\www\app\passengerJourneyDetails.php on line 3**

Comment: fix your code *Notice: Undefined index: select-   choice-1* php function isset() is your friend

Comment: True what @donald123 says, because any error/warning message = output, and after any output has been sent, no more headers can be set.

Comment: or add `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` to have notices ignored by php.

Comment: I cant really get it. Where exactly is the error in code above? should I initialize the $from, $to variables within the if(isset) statement or what?

Answer (score 0):

All calls to the `header()` function must be made before any output is sent to the browser (unless you use output buffering). Try changing your level of error reporting (or actually fixing the error itself).

For example, using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will help you to prevent such notices in the future:

```
if( isset($_POST['select- choice-1'] )
{
    $from = $_POST['select- choice-1'];
}
```

It's also worth noting that your code is wide-open to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attacks. The `mysql_*` family of functions is now deprecated and should not be used in production code. Investigate [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and more specifically, [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid such security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you form inputs names are not properly labeled.

```
<form action="exampled" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name"> 

  <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="First Name">

  <button type="submit" name="submit">signup</button>

</form>


$from=  $_POST['first'];
$to=  $_POST['last'];
```